# Logcat Error Constructor DataAdapter in class DataAdapter canot be appied

Tags: java, arraylist

Logcat:

```
  required:Context, ArrayList<AndroidVersion>
    found: ArrayList<AndroidVersion>
    reason:actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

ArrayList in my DataAdapter cannot be applied to my array list in Android Version

I believe this is about context, but I am unclear what line needs to be amended.

MainActivity.java where the word 'data' is throwing the error.

```
   package davidfoale.info.relativelayout_json;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.util.Log;
import java.util.Arrays;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String android_image_urls[] = {
            "http://davidfoale.info/images/app_images/vetsurgeon.jpg",
            "http://davidfoale.info/images/app_images/hairdresser.jpg",
            "http://davidfoale.info/images/app_images/vetsurgeon.jpg",
            "http://davidfoale.info/images/app_images/hairdresser.jpg",
            "http://davidfoale.info/images/app_images/vetsurgeon.jpg",
            "http://davidfoale.info/images/app_images/hairdresser.jpg",
            "http://davidfoale.info/images/app_images/vetsurgeon.jpg",
            "http://davidfoale.info/images/app_images/hairdresser.jpg",
            "http://davidfoale.info/images/app_images/vetsurgeon.jpg",
            "http://davidfoale.info/images/app_images/hairdresser.jpg",

    };

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> data;
    private DataAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initViews();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    private void initViews() {
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager
                = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        ArrayList androidVersions = prepareData();
        DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), androidVersions);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        loadJSON();
    }

    private void loadJSON(){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()

                .baseUrl("http://davidfoale.info/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

        Call<JSONResponse> call = request.getJSON();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {

                JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
                data    = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getAndroid()));
                adapter = new DataAdapter(data);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    private ArrayList prepareData() {
        ArrayList android_version = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < android_image_urls.length; i++) {
            AndroidVersion androidVersion = new AndroidVersion();
            androidVersion.setAndroid_image_url(android_image_urls[i]);
            android_version.add(androidVersion);
        }
        return android_version;
    }
}
```

DataAdapter.java

```
package davidfoale.info.relativelayout_json;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ScrollingView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import java.util.ArrayList;




public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android_versions, android;
    private Context context;

    public DataAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android_versions) {
        this.context = context;
        this.android_versions = android_versions;
        this.android = android_versions;
    }




    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }








    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        Picasso.with(context).load(android_versions.get(i).getAndroid_image_url()).resize(61, 65).into
                (viewHolder.img_android);

            // added from MySQL-Retrofit NOT Picasso
            viewHolder.job_desc.setText(android.get(i).getDesc());
            // end of added
            viewHolder.img_android.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Intent intent = new Intent(DataAdapter.this, GetDetails.class);
                Intent intent = new Intent (context, SecondActivity.class);
                //      in.putExtra("USE_A_CONSTANT_HERE_AS_KEY", ?);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }




    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return android_versions.size();
    }




    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView job_desc;
                ImageView img_android;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            img_android = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img_android);
            job_desc    = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.job_desc);
       }
    }
}
```

AndroidVersion.java

```
package davidfoale.info.relativelayout_json;

public class AndroidVersion {

    private String android_image_url;

    public String getAndroid_image_url() {
        return android_image_url;
    }
    public void setAndroid_image_url(String android_image_url) {
        this.android_image_url = android_image_url;
    }

    // added in to get desc data
    private String job_desc;

    public String getDesc() {
        return job_desc;
    }
    // end
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DataAdapter` class does NOT have the constructor to create the object like `new DataAdapter(data);`, so  inside `onResponse()` method you need to change from `adapter = new DataAdapter(data);` to `adapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), data);` or else provide a constructor in your `DataAdapter` class.